# Map in GridView

Tags: firebase, flutter

I'm with a problem making a GridView where the children are a array of images from firebase, i've already tried a lot of things like changing the List type, changing ImageNetwork to NetworkImage, making map, etc, but it's always giving me the same error "The method 'map' was called on null".

```
return Material(
  child: GestureDetector(
    child: FutureBuilder(
    future: Firestore.instance.collection("images-lessons").document("teste").collection("images-teste").getDocuments(),
    builder: (context, snapshot){
if(!snapshot.hasData){
return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
}
else {
  return GridView(
    physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
    gridDelegate:  SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
      children: imageLessonData.imageL.map((url){
        return Image.network(url);
      }).toList() ,);
}
    }),
  ),
);
```

Comment: "The method 'map' was called on null" message is because the member 'imageL' of  imageLessonData instance is NULL. Are you initializing your imageLessonData instance after you firestore query? I can't see this in your snippet.

Comment: yes, it's a final variable and i'm initializing in the constructor

Comment: Well the problem is imageL member is null. Reading your question I am guess that the member imageL means (image list) and the images that this list holds you wanna show in your gridview. What I can't see in your code is where you're creating and filling the image list after you get the images URL's from firestore. I think you forgot this.